# Can TrueCrypt like software protect my external HDD from virus in svhost.exe modify my files on it?

Tags: windows, virus, trojan

A 'shurtcut to (1).lnk' virus infected 50 000 of my html files on an external HDD. If I will encrypt data on it, will it protect them from trojan process being run on behalf svhost.exe?

Comment: Backups protect from viruses. Not encryption software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, encryption will do nothing to secure your files. you need regular backups.

If a truecrypt volume is mounted at the time malware runs, and the user the malware is executing under has write privileges to the volume, the malware can damage the files just as though they were unencrypted. Even if unmounted, malware may damage a volume .tc file, or even perform operations on the disk at the partition or raw level.

What encryption does help with in terms of malware is data exfiltration. if the malware wants to steal your data, then encryption will help, but keep in mind, if the volume is mounted, the malware can read it even if its encrypted at rest.

Another way encryption is used in the security field, is to isolate and contain malware samples when performing research. encrypting the file helps ensure it cannot be accidentally executed. Not really something normal people do, but worth noting.